# How to use key and value from two mapper to one reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two different files named A.txt and B.txt.

```
A.txt:                    B.txt
id  name    des          id  name
1   one     0            1   apple   
2   two     1            2   pine  
3   three   0            3   orange
```

Here, I have the same field "id" in both files.
I used two mapper class. One for A.txt and another for B.txt. There is one reducer class.

```
In MapperA.class "des" is checked and if "0" then its id is sent as key and value as name. 
In MapperB.class id and name is sent as key and value.
Now, in reducer I need to determine the "id" from MapperA and check with "id" from MapperB and if present, then send key as "id" and value as "name". 
How can we compare the key and value from two mapper in a reducer to get desired result?
```

The desired output from reducer is:

```
id      name
1       apple
3       orange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need comparison process in reduce function. 
There will be 2 seperate mapper class for each input A.txt and B.txt

**MAPPER FOR A.txt**
if(des == 0)
then
  write id, value-->des>// des will be TextWritable("0")
else
  don't write anything

**MAPPER FOR B.txt**

id, value-->apple or orange or pine...>

**Reducer**

input will be <1, { 0,apple}> <2, {pine} > <3, {0,orange} >

Then in reduce process

```
Boolean shouldBeWritten=false;
foreach value
{
  char firstLetter = first char of value;
  if( firstletter == 0 )
   shouldBeWritten=true;
}
if(shouldBeWritten)
write(key, value);
```

In this implementation you have to get first letter of fruitname as well which is not efficient but you won't have to send unnecessary  pairs in first mapper.

This is just an example decision is up to you.

The decision depends on size of a.txt and b.txt as well.

Comment: I need to determine ''id" by comparing the "des" value and pass that id to reducer.